# Service box with no neutral bar

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm trying to add a 30amp, 110V RV connection box to my house but the service box has no neutral bar, what do I do with the white neutral wire?

This is a picture of the main panel by the meter.

[image]

This is a picture of the garage sub panel where I will be adding the RV service box.

[image]

Comment: IF this is the main service panel then there HAS to be a neutral bar. In a main panel there is likely only one bar for both ground and neutral.
...... Can you post a pic of the panel?

Comment: Where are all of the other neutrals connected?

Comment: I think OP might be referring to a meter box.

Comment: See here for instructions on how to add a photo to your post http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer

Comment: Also, you appear to have two accounts. See http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts for how to merge them. Thanks!

Comment: Can you get us pictures or a model number of the RV service box?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. I thought that the neutral bar and ground bar could not be strapped together but I understand now, thanks again.

Comment: I don't see any grounds between the sub-panel and main panel.  On the other hand the exit fittings on the main panel look like EMT metal conduit fittings.  If so, that is the ground.  The neutral appears to be isolated from it in the sub-panel.  So it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you have four slots available at the garage panel on the left side of the panel in your picture and one in the upper right.

The neutral bar is on the bottom of your picture with the white wires.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Thanks ArchonOSX, so my ground bar is the one next to the neutral bar? Even though they are both tied together?

Comment: Yes they are both tied together at the service by the "main bonding jumper". This is the only place in the electrical system where the neutrals and equipment grounds are allowed to be bonded together. So the panel in your garage is a sub-panel and the neutral bar must be isolated from ground. That is why it is mounted on plastic. That panel could have a ground bar added to it. You could look for an add on ground bar kit for your panel. At the sub-panel the grounds and neutrals must remain separate.

Comment: Your panel appears to be a very old Square D QO style panel. QO breakers should fit it. If you add a ground bar you will have to drill and tap the panel to mount it. It should be tapped for a finer thread screw like a 10-32.

Answer (score 1):

You have a neutral bar.  You don't have a ground bar.  Your panels look exactly like mine, which feed all EMT metallic conduit, and the conduit is the ground path.  Care for it kindly, fix gaps immediately.

Your main panel has a neutral bar which appears to be all-metal and by nature bonded to the panel box (which is ground), which is both allowed and required in a main panel.

Your sub-panel has a neutral bar which is insulated from the panel box aka ground, which is required in a sub-panel.

Beware, on an isolated neutral bar, there are often special screws, usually green, which screw through the neutral bar to bond it to the case (ground).  You should take care that there are none of those on a sub-panel; on a main panel I would "belt and suspenders" that by also adding a bonding strap.

Comment: Thank you Harper, I understand it now, thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I see both a neutral bar and a ground bar strapped together with jumpers. I also see the required ground wire. There is nothing wrong with this installation other than the panel having very few breaker slots.
 You need a dedicated 2 pole breaker to connect a sub-panel to the main. Its amp rating should not exceed 50% of the main breaker rating. You can do what you want as long as you run another white neutral wire and ground wire back to the main panel.
The breakers in any sub-feed panel cannot exceed the rating of the sub-feed panel main breaker.
**NOTE:** *If the main panel does not have any spare breaker slots, you will have to shift the wires to any 240vac device to your new sub-feed panel, or buy a whole new panel*.